# How does the ImagePicker get analyzed by the MLModel?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, uiimagepickercontroller, mlmodel

I am still being confused about how to make the current image (selected from the gallery photos) identified by the machine learning model file. What I would like to do is that once the camera button is tapped then I am able to select a picture from the gallery pictures (this the part of the code which works). However once the photo is displayed, it does not trigger the ml model and the photo is not identified but just displayed as it is. Could anyone help me out, please?  This is my code:

```
import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var isShowPicker: Bool = false
    @State private var image: Image? = Image("")
    @State private var classificationLabel: String = ""
    
    let model = MobileNetV2()
    
     private func performImageClassification() {
         
        let currentImageName = ImagePicker(image: self.$image)
        guard let img = UIImage(named: "\(String(describing: currentImageName))"),
            let resizedImage = img.resizeTo(size: CGSize(width: 224, height: 224)),
        let pixelBuffer = resizedImage.toCVPixelBuffer() else {
            return
            
        }
        let output = try? model.prediction(image: pixelBuffer)
        if let output = output {
            self.classificationLabel = output.classLabel
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    image?
                        .resizable()
                    .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                        Button(action: {
                        
                            self.performImageClassification()
                            self.isShowPicker.toggle()
                            
                    
                    })
                    {
                        Image(systemName: "camera.fill")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    }.foregroundColor(.blue)
                        ).navigationBarBackButtonHidden(false)
                    .navigationBarTitle("\(classificationLabel)")
                    Text(classificationLabel)
                   
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isShowPicker) {
                ImagePicker(image: self.$image)
                 

            }
            
               
            .navigationBarTitle(Text(classificationLabel))
           
        }
    }
}

struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode)
    var presentationMode

    @Binding var image: Image?
    

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

        @Binding var presentationMode: PresentationMode
        @Binding var image: Image?

        init(presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>, image: Binding<Image?>) {
            _presentationMode = presentationMode
            _image = image
        }

        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                                   didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            let uiImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
            image = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
            presentationMode.dismiss()
            

        }

        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            presentationMode.dismiss()
        }

    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(presentationMode: presentationMode, image: $image)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController,
                                context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {
        

    }

}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ContentView()

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
import SwiftUI

class ImagePickerCoordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    
    @Binding var image: UIImage?
    @Binding var isShown: Bool
    
    init(image: Binding<UIImage?>,
         isShown: Binding<Bool>) {
        _image = image
        _isShown = isShown
    }
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let uiImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            image = uiImage
            isShown = false
        }
    }
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        isShown = false
    }
}

struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    typealias UIViewControllerType = UIImagePickerController
    typealias Coordinator = ImagePickerCoordinator
    
    @Binding var image: UIImage?
    @Binding var isShown: Bool
    var sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .camera
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> ImagePicker.Coordinator {
        ImagePickerCoordinator(image: $image, isShown: $isShown)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.sourceType = sourceType
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }
}
```